# Can not save a data.frame into Rdata or CSV file

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, rdata

I was trying to save a large dataframe (nrow x ncol = 40000 x 3000) into a Rdata file. I got it either saved as empty file or just failed to save it. The space in the saving directory was enough. I am wondering if the dataframe I was trying to save was too large and R just could not handle it. Or I was doing something wrong. Thanks everyone for viewing my question and thanks in advance for any of your help.

Here are some info of the dataframe I was trying to save

```
> object.size(DF)
888018736 bytes

> str(DF)
'data.frame':   44379 obs. of  2501 variables:
 $ Type: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X1             : num  329 153 352 135 338 347 138 130 332 126 ...
 $ X2             : num  317 133 360 125 347 342 130 122 345 127 ...

> table(sapply(DF, class))
 factor numeric 
      1    2500 

> DF[1:5,1:5]
  Extract Type  X1  X2  X3  X4
1            A 329 317 315 292
2            A 153 133 138 124
3            A 352 360 317 294
4            A 135 125 127 131
5            A 338 347 342 337
```

First, I tried "save" and it gave an error in writing connection

```
> save(DF, file = "testdata.Rdata")
Error in save(DF, file = "testdata.Rdata") : 
error writing to connection
```

Next, I tried "write.table". It processed but the Rdata file was empty

```
> write.table(DF, file = "testdata.RData")
```

Then, I tried "save.csv". It processed but the csv file was empty too

```
> write.csv(DF, file = "testdata.csv")
```

And then, I tried "save" with the compress parameter but got the connection error again.

```
> save(DF, file = "testdata.RData", compress = TRUE, compression_level=6)
Error in save(DF, file = "testdata.RData", compress = TRUE,  : 
error writing to connection
```

Overall, I was trying to save this large dataframe and hand it to others. If there are other file types I should try to save the dataframe to, please feel free to let me know. I am new to R and I really appreciate any of your help.

Comment: Do you have permission to write in the current working directory? See `getwd()` for the directory. You say an empty file was created for the  `write.table` methods? Do you have enough room on disk for the data?

Comment: Hi MrFlick, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have permission to write in the current working directory. Yes, both write.table and write.csv created an empty file.

Comment: Does `cat("Hello", file="test.txt")` work? (ie, produce a file called test.txt with the contents Hello)

Comment: Yes, cat("Hello", file="test.txt") works.

Comment: How did you make this `data.frame`? What's the output of `table(sapply(DF, class))`? (When you add new information, it's best to edit the original question rather than add comments if possible)

Comment: Also can you save subsets of the data? What about `write.table(DF[1:5, ], file = "testdata.txt")`? It's odd because i don't think the file is really all that large.

Comment: I've added the output of `table(sapply(DF, class))` in the original question. It seems that saving the subsets of the data does not work. `write.table(DF[1:5, ], file = "testdata.txt")` created an empty txt file.